# How to get the count of document from a selected indices

Tags: elasticsearch

The scenario that I am running into is, in my elastic cluster I have more then 500 indices. I want the count of document for all the indices whose index name starts with "Analytics" or contains "accounts" in the index name. How can I write the query?

I am using ES 7.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_cat/indices` API call with comma-seperated index patterns.

```
GET _cat/indices/*test*,*accounts*?v&h=index,docs.count
index                 docs.count
test_history-1                 1
test_history-2                 2
test_interesting_body          1
test_doc_remove                2
test_musab                     1
```

If you need a more complex query you can use the following query with `_index` field.

```
GET _all/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "_index": "*test*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "_index": "*accounts*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick tip to not having to use costly `wildcard` queries with prefix wildcard: just run the aggregation on `GET *test*,*accounts*/_search` with no query ;-)

Comment: will this query work for 5.x/

Comment: Yes it does work in any recent version of ES